# How do I implement a app-wide notification feature when there is a change in my Firestore collection in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3

I am currently developing an **ionic 3** project which has a chat feature implemented in it. I am using **firebase firestore** as my database.

My goal is to implement an `app-wide notification` feature that **triggers** when a new message is created in the `firestore chat collection` but I am having some difficulty in trying to accomplish that.

**Here is my :**

```
this.chat = this.firestoreProvider.getChatRooms(userEmail).valueChanges();
this.chat.subscribe(res=>{
// Triggered when there are changes in the firestore chat room collection
});
```

**Here is the code block in my `firestoreProvider`:**

```
getChatRooms(chatRoomOwnerEmail:string){    
   return this.firestore.collection("Chat Room", ref => ref.where("chatRoomOwnerEmail", "==", chatRoomOwnerEmail).orderBy("chatRoomLastMessage", "asc"));
}
```

I tried to put this method in my **app.component.ts** but it made my whole application crash when I did an `ionic serve`.

Are there any solutions on how I can implement this real-time `notification` feature with `firestore` that triggers across all pages in my application? (Meaning in all pages, the check for new messages in the chat room will keep on triggering).

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get the `real-time notification` out, but now I need to do something on my home page when there is a notification. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you're using `ionic`, you could use the `AppComponent` that hosts the `ion-nav` to listen for the change. And then show a toast for example when you get the response.

That way, even if the view changes, the `AppComponent` would still be on the view and would still be listening for changes.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { ToastController } from "ionic-angular";

import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "app.html"
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = TabsPage;
  changeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    private dataService: DataService,
    public toastController: ToastController
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeSubscription = this.dataService
      .listenForChange()
      .subscribe(response => {
        const toast = this.toastController.create({
          message: "Data Changed!",
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.changeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

> **NOTE:** I'm using Ionic V3 syntax in the answer as StackBlitz doesn't have a Template for V4 ATM. If you're using V4, the syntax might change slightly.
>
> You might also NOT want to `subscribe` to the `Observable` and rather use the `Observable` with an `async` pipe in the template instead. That way you'd be safe from any memory leaks. I'm subscribing to the `Observable` as I had to show the toast.
>
> Here's a [**Working Sample Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-show-toast-on-every-change) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. But I don't think firestore has a .listenForChange() method though.

Comment: Ah. That was just an example of something that would return an Observable. Instead of the `this.dataService.listenForChange()` method, you'd have your `this.chat` since that is an `Observable` as well. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get the real-time notification out, but now I need to do something on my home page when there is a notification. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I used that reference and understanding to implement the real-time updating. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly is your use case? What is it that you're planning to achieve here?

Comment: I have a firestore collection which stores the chat rooms + messages for each individual user. When there is a new chat message sent to the user, a notification will appear to tell them "XXX has sent you a message!". On top of the phone notification, In the home page, beside the chat icon I also want to display the number of new messages that came in. The displaying of the number of new messages in the home page is what I'm trying to accomplish now. Currently, I am able to detect new messages in the app.component and can console.log when a new message arrives.